# openstack error, unable to establish connection to endpoint

Tags: openstack

When I exploit `openstack` to build a network simulation, I encountered a problem like this.

`$ openstack server list`

```
unable to establish connection to 
http://nova-api-proxy.openstack.svc.cluster.local:8774
 /v2.1/a9e3d71fc89147e7aadd28179c03df6c/servers/detail: 
HTTPConnectionPool(host='nova-api-proxy.openstack.svc.cluster.local', port=8774):
 Max retries exceeded with url:
 /v2.1/a9e3d71fc89147e7aadd28179c03df6c/servers/detail
 (Caused by NewConnection Error('urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7faeab41b510>:
 Failed to establisha new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

After waiting for a period of time, execute `openstack server list` again, and this error will not appear. The irregular appearance of this error bothers me.

Comment: Your nova-api service seems to have interruptions, I would check logs to find out why that happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is the main reason: `Failed to establisha new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`.

Check your hostname `host='nova-api-proxy.openstack.svc.cluster.local'` could be **resolved correctly** in your `openstack` cluster including every **hypervisor, compute node, storage node, network node** and so on.

I have been met this situation because of the hypervisor host's **/etc/hosts** file update, but the component service's configure has not been update which our component service running with `docker` environment, I **restart the docker container** and fixed because it would reload automatically consistent with the host's **/etc/hosts** file.

And then if this can't fix your problem, you should check whether exist other error log in the component services's log directory.

After some time, you execute `openstack server list` again and the error would gone. In my view, there still has some unknown problem with `neutron` the network component, or some services which like `systemd-resolved.service -- Network Name Resolution` didn't ran successfully while you execute the command with error at first.